# Data redundancy on csv file

Tags: python

Hi Good day everyone I'm sorry I'm new to python programming sorry if I'm asking this even this is basic or not. Someone can help me with this?  My problem is I want to write the data that capture's on my open cv Like for example "Name" "Reputation" or something else. And write it to my csv file. It writes But I has a redundancy like per capture it records The same name. I just want one Name that don't redundant Someone can Help me with this Please???

Here's the code to record data to csv:

```py
def markattend(name, years, pos, tempe):
    with open('attendances.csv', 'r+') as f:
        datalist = f.readlines()
        nameList = []

        for line in datalist:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])

        if name and years and pos and tempe not in nameList:
            now = datetime.now()
            dtString = now.strftime('%I:%M:%a:%d:%b:%Y')
            f.writelines(f'\n{name},{years},{pos},{tempe},{dtString}')
        return datalist
```

And here I call the function and assigning its Data: like "Name" "Position"

```py
if confidence>70:
    cv2.putText(img, datas, (x,y+205), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(img, datas1, (x,y+230), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(img, datas2, (x,y+250), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(img, get_temp(ser), (x,y+280), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    markattend(datas,datas1,datas2,get_temp(ser))  # <== This temp is from my sensor data and datas, datas1, datas2   it correspond the "Name" "position" "Student"
```

Someone can help me   plsss

Here's my csv file photo:[here's the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7wpM.png)

Comment: Do you mean you'd like your program to read `attendances.csv` and also update `attendances.csv` as it goes, instead of saving a new CSV file with a different name?

Comment: Noo I mean That program above is Already writing the data capture on my open cv into csv file but it redundant every seconds. I want to remove the redundancy Help me please? @JackDeeth

Answer (score 1):

1. **do not parse [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) manually**:

```
import csv

data = []

with open('attendances.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    data.append(row)
```

2. ↓

```py
if name and years and pos and tempe not in nameList:
```

is the same as

```py
if name is True and years is True and pos is True and tempe not in nameList:
```

correct code is:

```py
import csv 

def markattend(name,years,pos,tempe):
    with open('attendances.csv','r+') as f:
    
        reader = csv.reader(f)
    
        for line in reader:
        
            if name == line[0] and years == line[1] and pos == line[2] and tempe == line[3]:
                ... do some stuff ...
```

Comment: Hi sir @rzvmp below the code you've give  I put the code like this

if name == line[0] and years == line[1] and pos == line[2] and tempe == [3]:
                now = datetime.now()
                dtString = now.strftime('%I:%M:%a:%d:%b:%Y')
                f.writelines(f'\n{name},{years},{pos},{tempe},{dtString}')

but it says index out of range

Answer (score 0):

```py
for line in datalist:
    entry = line.split(',')
    nameList.append(entry[0])
```

Only the names are being added to the `namesList` say:

```py
namesList = ['NameA', 'NameB']
```

The if statements used on your code does not work the way you think it does.

```
if 'NameC' and 'NameB' in namesList:
```

is going to evaluate it true, as you can see in the below snippet:

```
>>> namesList = ['NameA', 'NameB']
>>> 'NameC' and 'NameB' in namesList
True
>>> 'NameC' in namesList and 'NameB' in namesList
False
```

In your case, it is clear that `tempe` is not in the `namesList`, hence every entry is appended.